# Positioning elements within a page in Drupal 7

Tags: css, position, drupal-theming

I've got a set of divs in my page with some images inside of them. I would like them to be arranged horizontally instead of vertically ie:

```
 X X X X X
 X X X X X
```

Instead of

```
X
X
X
...
X
```

I've tried using the `float`, `position:absolute` properties but when using them the elements are "unattached" from the normal flow of the document and positioned outwith the content area.

What is the best way to position elements in such a way without altering the normal flow of the document?

**Edit**:

```
<div id="content" class="column"><div class="section">
  <h6 id="choose">CHOOSE WHAT YOUR PLANB IS</h6>
 <div class="region region-content">
  <div class="canvas-wrapper">
   <div class="canvas-triangle" id="one">
    <canvas id="one"></canvas>
   </div>
   <div class="triangle-caption">One</div>
 </div>
 <div class="canvas-wrapper">
   <div class="canvas-triangle" id="two">
     <canvas id="two"></canvas>
   </div>
   <div class="triangle-caption">Two</div>
 </div>
 //ANOTHER 8 LIKE THAT
 </div>
 </div>
```

That's the code I have that creates the divs with the images in them. What I would like to do is arrange them as indicated above. Let me know if you need any more details.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use position, just use float:left for the divs you want in a row. Than you can use some element with clear:left under those divs, so the divs will not overlay this element or any other element further in the code...

**edit:**

To understand it, try this code with and without clear:

```
#wrap {width: 500px; background:#ffa;}
div.row {float:left; width:150px; height:150px; background:#aff}
div.right {float:right; height:250px;}
div.clear {clear:left; width: 250px; background:#faf}

<div id="wrap">
    <div class="row"><p>div</p></div>
    <div class="row"><p>div</p></div>
    <div class="row"><p>div</p></div>
    <div class="row"><p>div</p></div>
    <div class="row right"><p>right</p></div>

    <div class="clear"><p>clear</p></div>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit...... </p>
</div>
```

Also notice the difference if you use clear with value left or both in this case.

Comment: The problem I have with using float:left is that the elements then stop being in the natural flow of the document and the footer pushes up too far.

Comment: I've added an example, I guess you need to understand how clear works.

Comment: I see what you mean but I think I'm explaining myself incorrectly. My problem is that when I use float the height of the `content` div becomes 0. And so the elements that are floating become "out of place" because they should be inside the content div. However, because of the float property, the content div thinks there's nothing inside of it and becomes really small, messing up the rest of the alyout. That's the best way I can think of describing it.

Comment: @KerrM: So I think what's you're saying here is basically it works in my example but it doesn't work in drupal? Drupal is a funny beast, there's usually so much css and html involved on even the most basic page, it can be extremely frustrating to get what you're aiming at. If this is the case, then you may want to just show us the site, or a replication containing the problem in jsfiddle.

Comment: Well if you add cleaner after those divs inside content, the height of content will not be 0, it will be from the top to the cleaner. If you look at my example, if you remove cleaner, #wrap (yellow background) has height:0. If you add the cleaner, wrap will end after the cleaner.

Comment: Yes that made it work. I added an empty div after all the image divs and gave it the clean:left property. It's displaying properly. Thanks both of you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the absolute positioning. You should give us something more to play with if that's not enough help.

EDIT: See this jsfiddle and let me know what's not clear: http://jsfiddle.net/FH7cg/.

Comment: Added some extra information on the structure of the divs within the content section. THanks for your reply

Comment: That's exactly what I need but my problem is that when I use float the height of the content div becomes 0. And so the elements that are floating become "out of place" because they should be inside the content div. However, because of the float property, the content div thinks there's nothing inside of it and becomes really small, messing up the rest of the alyout. That's the best way I can think of describing it. Thanks again for the prompt answers.