# CSS div footer and column height issue

Tags: css, html, height

I've got two problems here: http://jsfiddle.net/BtGtT/3

**The first problem** is that the footer should always be at the bottom of page, so if I change my "otherContent" `div` to be 75px instead of 1500px, the footer should remain at the bottom of the page (and not in the middle when I change it back to 1500px). I'm not sure how to update my CSS to make that happen.

**The second problem** is that I need my "contentLeft" and "contentRight" `div`s to always be the *same height* as my "contentCenter" `div`. So when I update my "otherContent" `div` to be 75px or 1500px like in the JSFiddle, the "contentLeft" and "contentRight" `div`s should match that. Is this possible?

In my actual web page, I've got an `<ASP:ContentPlaceHolder>` control and the content within could be of varying height. I'd like to keep my side columns the same height as whatever the center content might be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) and [Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/)

**More information:**

Read [this](http://css-tricks.com/7692-fluid-width-equal-height-columns/). CSS(2, at least) really struggles with this problem. So a few of your options are:

- Tiling an *image* with `repeat-y` to give the illusion of full length columns

  - Gradients also work if you can accept some graceful degradation
- Using Pseudo elements
- CSS3 Flexbox

All of these have their benefits, and differing browser support.

Just [read this article](http://css-tricks.com/7692-fluid-width-equal-height-columns/).

Comment: Thanks!! The footer seems to be working but I'm still having trouble w/ the left/right div height. I tried following @Jaa-c's example but it doesn't seem to work. Can you see what I might be doing wrong? [updated js fiddle at bottom of OP]

Answer (score 1):

In #divFooter, get rid of position and use clear:both. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304131/positioning-elements-within-a-page-in-drupal-7/8304224#8304224) for an example how clear works.

For the other question, check [this example](http://www.pixy.cz/blogg/clanky/css-3col-layout/).

Comment: Thank you. The footer seems to be working but I'm not sure why I can't get the left/right div heights to work correctly by following the example you provided. Can you see what I'm doing wrong? See updated JSFiddle.